# What is normal memory usage of an asp.net mvc website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, memory, memory-management, iis-7

I have really tried to Google it but only articles about how to troubleshoot memory issues come up. Before I start to troubleshoot, I would like to know if my web site's memory usage is really abnormal or not.

So it is an asp.net mvc 2 website that runs on IIS 7.5 in production. I guess normal memory usage depends upon traffic, so here are the numbers of an average day:

- 300 unique visitor
- 400 visits
- 3000 page views

I would be really happy to get some idea how much is the normal memory usage for this traffic. Also I would be curious to know how memory usage normally increases with traffic growth.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty imposible to define "normal memory usage" for anything without a more complete specification.

For example, if you cache large quantities of data in memory, that will affect the "normal memory usage" of your application. One thing that can particularly skew this is if the data is cached in response to a user action. There could be a scenario that users trigger on one in a thousand visits to your site that causes 75Mb of additional data to be cached, which might (depending on the usual dataset) cause what appears to be a significant difference.

Comment: I agree - You might want to use a memory profiler to look for memory leaks.